# npm install less but can't require via node

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, less

mac os x `10.10.5`

my node and npm version.

```
node -v
v4.2.1
npm -v
2.14.7
```

then refer to [official website](http://lesscss.org/) I install less.

```
sudo npm install -g less
sudo npm install -g less-plugin-clean-css
```

and I confirm that successfully installed in `node_modules`

```
ls /usr/local/lib/node_modules/

appcelerator    generator-webapp    ios-sim         yo
bower           grunt-cli       less
cordova         gulp            less-plugin-clean-css
express         ionic           npm
```

but when I use node command line to require less, some error occured..

```
> var less = require('less')
Error: Cannot find module 'less'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at repl:1:12
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:164:27)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:393:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
>
```

I google it but find nothing which could solve it, please some help ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require` doesn't load global modules by default. the modules must be located in the local `node_modules` folder.
If you really want to use global modules, you can set the NODE_PATH env variable (but this is bad practice in my opinion):

```
export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/
```

[Here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders) is some background information.

Answer (score 1):

i think your less module in not install perfectly,
As you used command sudo npm install -g less It install Less module globally,

Now you redirect your terminal to your project folder and Use the Following Command **sudo npm install less** ,remember use it without using -g.

For more information you can visit the [enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/less)

Answer (score -1):

I'm install it locally, without '-g' flag in working folder and now it works. 
You should open issue on their [gitbug](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues) if you want to install it correctly globally.